# Unable to generate SSL certificate through XAMPP

Tags: ssl, openssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

I have been trying to generate a SSL certificate for local testing. When I `cd` into `/xampp/apache/` and run `makecert` I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Can't open config file: ./bin/openssl.cnf
...
Error opening Private Key privkey.pem
```

How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wrong path to the openssl.cnf in the makecert.bat.

Just edit makecert.bat to fix the path:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=./conf/openssl.cnf
```