# Enabling SSL with XAMPP issue in windows 10

Tags: apache, http, batch-file, https, xampp

I have an issue with **XAMPP** when I try to setup `http` to `https` in local server. I flowing this [instruction](http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords). When I run `makecert.bat` file using `cmd` then terminal show flowing error.

[image]

```
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
......+++
..................................+++
writing new private key to 'privkey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
18548:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:.\crypto\ui\ui_lib.c:830:You must type in 4 to 511 characters
18548:error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:116:
18548:error:0907E06F:PEM routines:DO_PK8PKEY:read key:.\crypto\pem\pem_pk8.c:130:
unable to load Private Key
11920:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
server.csr: No such file or directory
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\server.csr
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

-----
Das Zertifikat wurde erstellt.
The certificate was provided.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't understand how to fix this error. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855868/unable-to-generate-ssl-certificate-trough-xampp). But it's not working. I found useful link [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=256495&sid=c7a65fa181503f991427450c046cac6f) about the `makecert.bat` file.

> I don't understand how to fix this issue. I need help.

- My **XAMPP** version: `7.1.11-0-VC14`
- Windows Edition: `Windows 10 Education`
- Version: `1709`
- OS Build: `16299.64`

Answer (score 0):

First of all for what you create self signed here you can create commercial certs for free: https://sslforfree.com

And here example how to add multiple ssl certificates for multiple domains to xampp server https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzGTgAaDP40

You can install php, apache2 and mysql without xampp search on youtube (windows server 2012 apache2, php, mysql).

Comment: youtube link is outdated

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue.
You have more than one xampp installation.
If you go to your original installed xampp/apache folder, makecert works perfect.